# Definition and properties of Pin group

Tags: clifford-algebras

$V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$, $Q$ is a non-degenerate quadratic form on $V$, $Cl(V,Q)$ is the Clifford algebra.

1. The Wikipedia article "Clifford algebra" says:

> The pin group $Pin_V (K)$ is the subgroup of the Lipschitz group $Γ$
> of elements of spinor norm 1

2. The Wikipedia article "Clifford algebra" and "Pin group" says:

> The pin group $Pin_V (K)$ is the subset of the Clifford algebra
> $Cl(V,Q)$ consisting of elements of the form $v_1 v_2 \cdots v_k$,
> where the $v_i$ are vectors such that $Q(v_i)=\pm 1$

I think $1$ is the best definition since it is directly related to the exact sequence $1\to{\pm 1}\to Pin_V (K)\to O_V(K)\to K^{\times}/{K^{\times}}^2$.

And $2$ is better to be regarded as a property of the pin group.

But how to prove $2$ is equivalent to $1$? At least in the process to prove $2\to 1$ I have such problems:

First according to $1$, spinor norm here is defined as $x^t x$ where $x$ is any element of $Cl(V,Q)$, and for elements from $Γ$ (as a subset of $Cl(V,Q)$) the spinor norm will be in $K^{\times}$ (as the grade $0$ vector subspace of $Cl(V,Q)$).

Also according to $1$, for elements $x$ from $V$ (as the grade $1$ vector subspace of $Cl(V,Q)$), $x^t =x$.

Also since $v_i$ is from $V$, then ${v_i}^2=Q(v_i)$.

So the spinor norm of elements of the form described by $2$ is:

$$(v_1 v_2 \cdots v_k)^t(v_1 v_2 \cdots v_k)=({v_k}^t \cdots {v_1}^t)(v_1 v_2 \cdots v_k)=(v_k \cdots v_1)(v_1 v_2 \cdots v_k)=Q(v_1) \cdots Q(v_k)=\pm 1$$

So the spinor norm is $\pm 1$, not the same as $1$ describes.

Comment: Definition (1) is incorrect. As you thought, it should say spinor norm $\pm1$. Spinor norm $1$ only suffices if $-1$ is a square in $K$. With that correction, I agree that (1) is preferable as a definition; it readily generalizes to non-degenerate $Q$ whereas (2) is incorrect in that case.

Comment: Something else to note: there are two things called "the spinor norm" here. One is $\sigma(x) = x^tx$ as you wrote (and it should be mentioned that $t$ is the main anti-involution). The other is $$\sigma_2(x) = (x^tx)K^{\times2} \in K^\times/K^{\times}.$$ The reason to care about $\sigma_2$ is that it's definable on $O(V)$. However, $\sigma_2$ is inappropriate in defining $\mathrm{Pin}$ since  e.g. when $K = \mathbb R$ $$K^\times/K^{\times} \cong \{\pm1\}.$$

Comment: Finally, for (2) $\implies$ (1) you just need to apply the definition of the Lipschitz group, and (1) $\implies$ (2) is [Cartan–Dieudonné](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%E2%80%93Dieudonn%C3%A9_theorem)

Comment: Where I wrote $K^\times/K^{\times}$ it should be $K^\times/K^{\times2}$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Thanks!

Comment: There's more subtlety to (1) than I was thinking at first. See this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251288/definition-of-pin-groups